# Method not found error in ASP.NET Core app with Json.NET/NEST/Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, json.net, nest

I have two projects in one solution, Project 1 and Project 2.

**Project 1.** Target Framework is .NET Core 2.1. It's an MVC project with controllers and views. It has a reference to Project 2. Nuget packages include:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
- Microsoft.NETCore.App

**Project 2.** Target Framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1. It is a class library that gets data using NEST/ElasticSearch. I'm on a time crunch so I'm basically copying over this project from a .NET Framework 4.5.1 project that runs just fine. Nuget packages include:

- NEST 1.7.1
- ElasticSearch.Net 1.7.1
- Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3

**Error in Project 2:**

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting this error if I am using the exact same code as the old 4.5.1 project. The only real difference is it is in the same solution as a .NET Core 2.1 project now.

**Things I've considered:**

- I tried upgrading the old project from .NET Framework 4.5.1 to .NET
  Framework 4.6.1. and it still runs fine, so I don't think it has to do with that.
- My hunch is that the ASP.NET Core project uses Newtonsoft.Json 10/11, while the .NET Framework 4.6.1 project uses Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1 and that is somehow causing the problem. But if this is the case, what is the solution? Upgrading Project 2 to Newtonsoft.Json 10/11 also requires you to update NEST and ElasticSearch.Net which introduce a ton of breaking changes. Ideally I wouldn't have to touch the code in Project 2 very much. I would really like to get this to work but keep Project 1 in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and not have *both* projects in the old .NET Framework.

Comment: In Json.NET 7.0.1, [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/7.0.1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L213) had a parameterized constructor taking a `bool` argument.   It was marked as obsolete but did exist.  But in [Commit 1914b91](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/1914b91bdb7bbaad7360b2094aae3766d45f2cd7#diff-b115497a548ad5ac106f393cc1efb170) on Jan 28, 2017 that constructor was removed.  It's clear that, for some reason, your **Project 2** is expecting the constructor to still exist.

Comment: @dbc, Since the second project is using Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1, I think it is normal that it expects that, no?

Comment: But honestly it's not clear what you are doing.  Are you trying to combine .Net core and .Net framework DLLs, each using different versions of Json.NET, into one executable?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - well not necessarily because there was also a default constructor.  So either `ElasticContractResolver` was using the parameterized constructor, or the call to the default constructor was optimized into a call to the parameterized constructor (since the default constructor did in fact call the parameterized) when **Project 2** was built.

Comment: @dbc, I see thanks!

Comment: @dbc I guess I am trying to run .NET Core and .NET Framework projects  alongside each other inside one solution and be able to make use of the existing NEST 1.7.1 code. It seems like each project might need different versions of Newtonsoft.Json to fix it but I'm not sure? It will be deployed to Windows/IIS so it doesn't have to be packaged so it can run on, say, a Linux machine. Doesn't really matter to me if it's one executable or two, as long as I can directly call Project 2 from Project 1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hunch is correct! You have a slight case of [DLL HELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

There are a few things that you can do and here is the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) that you can choose from

I personally like to edit app.config file so I will suggest that.

```
<dependentAssembly>  
  <assemblyIdentity name="YOUR JSON ASSEMBLY HERE"  
    publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
    culture="en-us" />  
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />  
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: So I would just edit the app.config file of Project 2? And this will allow Project 1 to use Newtonsoft 10/11 and Project 2 to use Newtonsoft 7?

Comment: @Derek Yes that is correct! That is what assemblybinding is for. It will tell your Project 2 to use version 7 (or whatever you choose :) )

Comment: It doesn't seem like that worked. I still get the same error.

Comment: @derek, it seems like you are either doing something wrong or there are other settings in your projects that you are not sharing. Assembly binding is exactly for solving different versions of same dll